# Display and update data without refreshing

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the information in json file on a simple HTML page, updating it in real time without the need to refresh the page.
I write a code but I does not work.
and If it works, I don't know if it will update the data without refreshing the page.  Where is my mistake?

**ex.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

</head>
<body>
<div id="myData"></div>
<script>
    fetch('data.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        });
    function appendData(data) {
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[i].name + ' ' +'Number: ' + data[i].number + ' ' +'Age: ' + data[i].age + ' ' +'Description: ' + data[i].description + ' ' +'Age: ' + data[i].age_float;
            mainContainer.appendChild(div);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**data.json**

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Sep 7, 2020 00:21:00 UTC",
    "updated_1": "2020-09-07T00:21:00+00:00",
    "updated_2": "Sep 7, 2020 at 16:13 BST"
  },
  "disclaimer": "Made by user...",
  "chartName": "Example",
  "exp": {
    "Steph": {
      "name": "STEPH",
      "number": "111",
      "age": "1",
      "description": "This is the first data",
      "age_float": 1111.1111
    },
    "Alex": {
      "name": "ALEX",
      "number": "2222",
      "age": "2",
      "description": "This is the second data",
      "age_float": 2222.2222
    },
    "Mitch": {
      "name": "MITCH",
      "number": "333",
      "age": "3",
      "description": "This is the third data",
      "age_float": 3333.3333
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Data is not an array so it has no `length`. What errors occur in browser dev tools console? Are you running this on a localhost server? You can't use `fetch()` in `file://` protocol

Comment: it is just a html page. What can I use instead of     fetch?

Comment: You can't make remote ajax request to the json file from `file://` at all. There are numerous easy ways to get a localhost server running on your machine so you can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment your problem is only related to your code assuming a wrong data format (just console.log data.length would demonstrate it)

And no, this will not trigger a page reload. Your code will work with the DOM API to manipulate the barely empty page that has been loaded as soon as your data is available in your fetch callback (assuming that your file is available along your html file on an HTTP server).

As a side note, you could perform your appends in a document fragment in order to build your element out of the DOM and append when every thing is ready.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <div id="myData"></div>
    <script>
      fetch("data.json")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(appendData)
        .catch(console.error);

      function appendData(data) {
        const dataFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (const user of Object.values(data.exp)) {
          dataFragment.appendChild(createUserElement(user));
        }
        document.getElementById("myData").appendChild(dataFragment);
      }

      function createUserElement(user) {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = `
            name: ${user.name} number: ${user.number} age: ${user.age} description: ${user.description} age: ${user.age_float}
        `;
        return div;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which can be tested assuming that [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) is available on your machine by running

`http-server -p 8000 .`

In your working directory and then visiting `http://localhost:8000/ex.html`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some refresh logic, because this script will only once per page refresh. You should wrap this code in a function and trigger this code with a button or with `setInterval()`.